# Asymptotic Expansion of MGF of squared Poisson - Touchard Polynomials and Second stirling number

Tags: probability, statistics, asymptotics, poisson-distribution, stirling-numbers

What is the asymptotic expansion of the following expression as $\theta \to 0^+$? Alternatively, what is the asymptotic expansion of the MGF $M(\theta)$ of the squared Poisson(1) as $\theta \to 0^+$?

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\theta^n}{n!} \left\{\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{k^{2n}}{k!}\right\}$$

I was able to use properties of the Stirling numbers of the second kind to write it as $$e \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\theta^n}{n!} \left\{\sum_{k=0}^{2n} S(2n, k)\right\}$$

but haven't been able to figure out how to proceed. Has this been studied before? Thank you.

Comment: It is $\infty$ for all $\lambda >0$. For  $\lambda \leq 0$ compte the square in $\lambda x^{2}-x$.

Comment: You can get proper braces (and other paired delimiters) that adapt to the size of their content by preceding them with `\left` and `\right`.